# How to change a DB table name in Orchard (add table prefix)?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm a total beginner in Orchard and in MVC in general, but googleing this I haven't found a solution.

I created a new Orchard site from source and after a few days of creating HelloWorld-like modules/parts/widgets I decided I want to implement a multi-tenant solution.

**Having already some content created which I don't want to lose, I'm wondering if I could somehow just rename all existing tables by adding a table prefix like 'Tenant1_' for all my DB tables?**

I tried adding a DataPrefix to ~\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt and manually renamed all the tables in the DB, but that generated an "Invalid object name 'Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord'." error.

My next step was going to be to try to add a new migration which would rename all the tables but I'm at a loss of what to do exactly. Am I trying to solve this in a totally wrong way?

I'm using SqlServer and VS2012.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't attempt to rename tables. Instead, create new ones and then move data. Even that is tricky and dangerous, so backup first.

Answer (score 1):

I think manual renaming doesn't work because all table mappings are cached in ~\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default\mappings.bin

Try to delete it.

Comment: Thanks, but deleting the mappings.bin file produced the same result. _Invalid object name 'Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord'_ Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord'. Source File: (removed)\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs    Line: 334. I assume that it would report the same error for all the tables in the DB, but this is the first that was hit.